# Connect to minikube cluster running on VM by kubectl from local machine

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have installed and running `minikube` cluster with `--driver=none` on Ubuntu 22 virtual machine.
Everything looks fine but I don't know how to connect to this cluster from my `k9s` or simple by `kubectl` from my local computer.
Is it possible?

Comment: What is an output from `minikube ip`? Are you using VBox, Hyper-V or anything else? Did you assigned IP to VM that is visible from the host machine? In general to access from host machine you need to use VM IP

Answer (score -1):

Check if minikube is running then you can use dashboard which will give you local minikube cluster link to open in browser and verify your cluster.

```
minikube status

minikube dashboard
```

Comment: minikube status is ok, but url generated by minikube dashboard is not possible to access on virtual machine

Comment: You will need to port forward to access from local machine, something like below

ssh -L <local_port>:localhost:<dashboard_port> {user_name}@vm_ip

replace with correct values

Comment: when I use ssh tunnel, the dashboard runs as expected.
minikube ip shows the same ip as a use for ssh access to vm.

Comment: If IP is the same and `ssh -L` make it works, so you just need to add `--listen-address=0.0.0.0` to add `minikube start` command to allow remote access without `ssh`